# config reply channel for message Gateway for handling responses on messages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have configured a tcp server with spring integration

this is server code:

```
 <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="serverInboundChannelAdapter"
                                    channel="fromTcpChannel"
                                    connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="serverOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                     channel="toTcpChannel"
                                     connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory"/>

<int:channel id="fromTcpChannel" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="toTcpChannelLogger" log-full-message="true"/>
<int:channel id="toTcpChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="toTcpChannelLogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="fromTcpChannel"
                       ref="serverMessageHandler"
                       method="handleMessage" />


<bean id="serverConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioServerConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="1234"/>
    <property name="singleUse" value="false"/>
    <property name="deserializer" ref="serverTcpDeserializer"/>
    <property name="serializer" ref="serverTcpSerializer"/>
</bean>



<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="com.last.webApp.webApp.config.sendMessage">
    <int:method name="send" request-channel="toTcpChannel" />
</int:gateway>



<bean id="serverMessageHandler" class="com.last.webApp.webApp.config.MessageHandler" />

<bean id="clientResponseHandler" class="com.last.webApp.webApp.config.handleResponse" />

<bean id="clientTcpSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer" />

<bean id="serverTcpSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer" />

<bean id="clientTcpDeserializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer" />

<bean id="serverTcpDeserializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer" />
```

now i need to recieve client act after sending a message to them and one solution is save the latest device per session in a model and handel the response in handleMessage method which is connceted to fromTcp method

```
    public class MessageHandler implements org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler {

    // Inbound channel
    
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

     //process

       }
```

Suddenly i saw **reply-channel=""** property for gateway and i thought that i can configure a new channel for it and handle replys in this way but it didnt work
somthing like this:

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="com.last.webApp.webApp.config.sendMessage">
    <int:method name="send" request-channel="toTcpChannel" reply-timeout="30000"  reply-channel="clientResponse" />
</int:gateway>

    <int:channel id="clientResponse" />

    <int:service-activator input-channel="clientResponse"
                           ref="clientResponseHandler"

                          method="handleResponse" />
```

Can i handle that in this way? or is there any other way to handle it with integration?
any help is appericiated

Answer (score 0):

No; you can't do that with TCP adapters because the reply channel header information is lost; use a `<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway/>` instead of the pair of adapters. That way, the reply channel info is retained in the gateway until the reply is received.

There is no need to specify a reply channel, it is handled internally by the framework.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. as you said i defined a `<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway` and beacuse it needs to bind to a **clinet connection** factory i created one like this `<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory type="client" id="tcpServer" using-nio="true" single-use="false" deserializer="clientTcpDeserializer" serializer="clientTcpSerializer"
port="1234" host="localhost"/>`  and as you said if i remove the inbound gateway,server refuses accepting new connection and it does not work . I got a bit stuck, what should i do with server connection factory?When i configure both clinet and server i receive timout

Comment: the timout is related to receving response from clinet while nothing is being sent to client and again the message like a loop is recevied by server, it noticable that each connection is opened 3 times. Could you please clearify that by writing some code?